# Laptop external monitor

Tags: external-monitor, display-manager

Hoping somebody can help

I have a dell G5 5587 laptop running Hera, I have connected to external monitor via HDMI cable.

when the laptops lid is closed I can work on the external. when the laptop gets suspended I can wake it up with USB connected keyboard/mouse

It wont however automatically start the display on the external monitor, i need to open the laptop and login and then it will.

Any solution?

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same problem.